# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'select' of null in magento 2.1

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, magento2

I'm having an issue with Magento 2.1 custom module. On loading a Magento admin page I'm having the following error in console.

> configure.js:76 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'select' of null

Comment: probably an error on line 76 - perhaps use the browser developer tools to investigate

Comment: Hi @JaromandaX configure.js error? How can i edit the same? I just wrote a layout file and on loading the same it showing the error. Can you describe the cause for the same?

Comment: No. You've shown no code to examine

Comment: Voting to close, as it needs an [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

did you override :

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/templates/catalog/product/composite/configure.phtml
```

It seems this file is trying to get the value from there :

```
vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/web/catalog/product/composite/configure.js

this.blockMsg                   = $('product_composite_configure_messages');
this.blockMsgError              = this.blockMsg.select('.message.error div')[0];
```

Comment: Hi @Tim Zwinkels, I included following scripts in 2 phtml files

`<script>
require([
"prototype","Magento_Sales/order/create/form","Magento_Catalog/catalog/product/composite/configure","domReady!"
], function(){
    order.sidebarHide();
    if (window.productConfigure) {
   productConfigure.addListType('product_to_add', {
        urlFetch: '<?php echo $block->getUrl('adminhtml/create/configureProductToAdd') ?>'
        });
    productConfigure.addListType('items', {
        urlFetch: '<?php echo $block->getUrl('adminhtml/create/configureQuoteItems') ?>'
        });}});
</script>`